# How can I avoid automatically starting a workflow?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I created an approval workflow with SharePoint Designer 2010.

The workflow starts if a new item has been created in the list. After the item has been approved, this workflow is using the method "Set field in current item" to update some field values of the list item.

And there is my problem:

I have another workflow which should only run if a item has been edited by a user. The problem is, that this workflow will be automatically triggered by the above workflow, when it updates the field values.

Is there any chance to avoid this without coding?

The best would be to tell the Edit workflow not to start before the New Workflow is finished.

I tried already within the Edit Workflow to check if the status of the New Workflow is "Completed" and not "In Progress" but this seems not to work.

Would be very happy if someone could help me?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I don't think you need code

> should only run if a item has been edited by a user

Check the `ModifiedBy` field with your Edit Workflow, so it only runs when **not** modified by System (or whatever your workflow is running as)

> check if the status of the New Workflow is "Completed"

This should work. You can check in the Edit Workflow whether the field for your Workflow Status is Completed or whatever else value.

Try posting a screenshot (you can edit your original question) if the problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

I would create the secondary workflow to also fire on a specific condition.  You said the initial workflow sets some field values.  I would create a hidden field in this list as a tracking mechanism, a basic number column with a default of 0.

When you want the secondary workflow to fire, you set the field value in your primary workflow to 1.  Then your secondary workflow fires on change and evaluates if the field equals 1.  If it does not, the workflow ends.  If it does, the workflow continues on.